# How to draw a column chart and and line charts using rcousens/AmCharts bundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, amcharts

I've started using [rcousens/AmCharts](https://github.com/rcousens/AmChartsBundle%20%22rcousens/AmCharts) Bundle for my charts. I've checked `AmCharts` itself and I think it would perfectly fit my needs. I've also tried the demo pie chart in the rcousens/AmCharts tutorial and it worked fine. Although there are no docummentation for other charts and all the methods of the bundle are without any documentation. How do I draw Column chart, Line chart and Column and